# How to properly configure this dummy Angular project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have this very basic project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktmgc-ktjk3n?file=index.html

This is the code on: `/index.html`

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="mat-app-background basic-container">
    <br />
    <a href="https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api">API reference for Angular Material slide-toggle</a><br /><br />
    <select-reset-example>loading</select-reset-example>
    <div style="margin-top:30px;">
    <div style="color:#f00;margin-bottom:20px;">
          Below is what I need to get it work like above (but it doesn't):
    </div>
        <mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code on: `/app/select-reset-example.html`

```
<mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
```

When loading the component: `mat-slide-toggle` through: `select-reset-example` it works, but when loading it directly on the `index.html` it doesn't.

My question is, how to configure the following `/main.ts` file in order to render the `mat-slide-toggle` directly on the `index.html`?

In case the scope be a problem, maybe is it possible to create a custom component which inherits from that `mat-slide-toggle` or `MatSlideToggleModule` class?

If possible, could you fork the project on `stackblitz.com` and give me the link
with a proper configuration?

```
import './polyfills';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material';
import { SelectResetExample } from './app/select-reset-example';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatSlideToggleModule,
  ]
})
export class DemoMaterialModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [SelectResetExample],
  declarations: [SelectResetExample],
  bootstrap: [SelectResetExample],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

This is the structure of the project:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to use a module inside your app, and index.html is outside the scope. I'd suggest hitting up the Tour of Heroes to get acquainted with Angular, and general concepts like module and app scope.

Comment: I just checked, https://material.angular.io is up and running. Why not read up and configure this yourself?

Comment: @Z.Bagley, is it possible to create a custom class which inherits from that component or module to have it on the same scope?

Comment: Feel free to check out: https://github.com/zbagley/ngx-flex-material-template to see how material is normally implemented through multiple modules in a project

Comment: I think the app bootstraps from SelectResetExample component. See `bootstrap: [SelectResetExample],` in `main.ts` file. Anything outside this component is not compiled by angular, and not considered as angular components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there are several options which could be applied here.

### Attempt 1

At first glance we can easily solve your problem by simply importing `MatSlideToggle` component and adding it to the `bootstrap` array:

```
import { MatSlideToggle } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  ...
  bootstrap: [SelectResetExample, MatSlideToggle ]
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                               cool, it was very easy!!!
})
export class AppModule { }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktmgc-7h51hh?file=main.ts

Hmm, seems we've broken everything:).

**Why?**

Angular bootstraps `SelectResetExample` component. During this process it creates `mat-slide-toggle` that is part of `select-reset-example.html` template.

So now our html has two `mat-slide-toggle` tags.

And then angular bootstraps second component (`MatSlideToggle`) that will be applied to the first `mat-slide-toggle`. This way we can see that the first working slider lost text `Slide me!`.

### Attempt 2

Let's change order of our bootstrapping components:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  bootstrap: [ MatSlideToggle, SelectResetExample ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktmgc-mkm7ry?file=main.ts

The second slider works now but wait... We again lost the text.

The main reason of this is that **angular can't process projectable nodes on bootstrapping component.**

### Attempt 3

Angular gives the opportunity to override bootstrapping process by writing code within `ngDoBootstrap` method of `@NgModule`. Let's try...

```
import { ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Injector, NgModuleRef } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  // we replaced bootstrap option with entryComponents
  entryComponents: [SelectResetExample, MatSlideToggle],
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private ngModule: NgModuleRef<any>) {}

  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {

    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MatSlideToggle);
    const target = document.querySelector('mat-slide-toggle');
    const compRef = factory.create(
       Injector.NULL,
       [Array.from(target.childNodes)], // passing projectable nodes
       target, 
       this.ngModule);

    appRef.attachView(compRef.hostView);


    appRef.bootstrap(SelectResetExample);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktmgc-ncyebq?file=index.html

Here i am bootstrapping our components throught custom method `ngDoBootstrap`. And it works but...

**What is this? Do I really need to know this?**

I don't think so. There must be some other way out.

### Attempt 4

in order not to complicate our live we should follow the design of angular framework. For that it would be better to have one root component. Let's create it:

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: '.mat-app-background.basic-container',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<br />
<a href="https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api">API reference for Angular Material slide-toggle</a><br /><br />
<select-reset-example>loading</select-reset-example>
<div style="margin-top:30px;">
  <div style="color:#f00;margin-bottom:20px;">
    Below is what I need to get it work like above (but it doesn't):
  </div>
  <mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

**module**

```
declarations: [SelectResetExample, AppComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="mat-app-background basic-container"></div>
```

i moved styles to external resouces

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktmgc-n9tfli?file=index.html)**